# How to overcome SonarQube's missing distinction between unit tests and integration tests?

Tags: sonarqube, junit5

There is no distinction in SonarQube between unit tests and integration tests. That is a problem.

We have large tests (or integration tests) which stretch across external systems. When these tests fail, only by human evaluation it can be decided whether it is a failure of our application or of the external system. If it is a external system failure than we can ignore it.

If SonarQube would have the distinction between unit tests and integration tests, then I would configure that the quality gate fails if more than 0 unit tests fail and allow integration tests to fail.

Because there is no such distinction anymore in SonarQube we have to solve it in the Jenkins pipeline, expecting all non-large tests (unit tests) to succeed and allowing large tests (integration tests) to fail.

I would prefer not to display any test results in the Jenkins build but have it only in SonarQube. But SonarQube is not capable of that logic and it does not separate the test results (large and non-large).

Maybe SonarQube will reconsider that decision to combine all different kinds of test results? It should be even more flexible than unit/integration tests and allow groups of test to be customized, like small/medium/large tests, with quality gates for each of them.

Or is there a better solution then we currently use?

Comment: What about applying some kind of naming convention and filtering/excluding based on that?

Comment: FYI you can make feature suggestions at https://community.sonarsource.com/c/suggestions

Comment: The naming convention would be a workaround. But then we do not have the code coverage of the integration tests in SonarQube. I think I will suggest a feature.